# Heroku Toolbelt on Fedora 17

Tags: ruby, fedora, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to do the heroku setup portion of the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/.  But on https://toolbelt.heroku.com/, I noticed there isn't an .rpm for Fedora, so I tried to install Foreman and the Heroku CLI individually.  Foreman and Git installed fine, but I'm having trouble with the Heroku CLI.

When I try to do:

```
$yum install rubygem-heroku
```

and then subsequently do simply

```
$heroku
```

I get the error:

```
   /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.8, actionpack-3.2.8, activemodel-3.2.8, activerecord-3.2.8, activeresource-3.2.8, activesupport-3.2.8, addressable-2.3.2, arel-3.0.2, builder-3.0.4, builder-3.0.3, bundler-1.2.3, bundler-1.2.1, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.4.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, erubis-2.7.0, excon-0.16.10, execjs-1.4.0, foreman-0.60.2, heroku-api-0.3.7, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.1.4, jquery-rails-2.1.3, jquery-rails-2.0.2, json-1.7.5, launchy-2.1.2, libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux, mail-2.4.4, mime-types-1.19, multi_json-1.5.0, multi_json-1.3.6, netrc-0.7.7, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-3.2.8, railties-3.2.8, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12, rest-client-1.6.7, rubygems-bundler-1.1.0, rubyzip-0.9.9, rvm-1.11.3.5, sass-3.2.3, sass-3.2.1, sass-rails-3.2.5, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, sqlite3-1.3.5, therubyracer-0.10.2, thor-0.16.0, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.12, treetop-1.4.11, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.35, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.3.0, uglifier-1.2.3, uglifier-1.0.3] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'
```

So I yum removed it and tried to instead do:

```
$rvmsudo gem install heroku
```

Now when I run heroku, I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/heroku-2.33.5/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Trying `rvm info` yields

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux angelo 3.6.5-1.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 31 19:37:18 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "redhat/17./x86_64"
    bash:        "/usr/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.16.6 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "2 months 20 days 1 hour 33 minutes 52 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/angelo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/angelo/heroku-client/:/home/angelo/.local/bin:/home/angelo/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rails3tutorial2ndEd"
```

And my rails version

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

Gem env:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I am pretty new to this whole ruby (as well as heroku), so I'm not sure what I should be looking for to match up, but everything seems to be ruby-1.9.3, so I am confused as to why Heroku doesn't want to cooperate.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a stand alone version of the toolbelt now available at https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone.

Answer (score 3):

I rather used the heroku and the foreman gem than using the heroku tool bet on fedora 17/18.

```
gem install heroku 
gem install foreman
```

during installation it will give a warning saying

> The `heroku` gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.

Ignore that. The toolbet even gave me problems on windows system.

All else works fine on Fedora 17/18.

Enjoy Rubying!

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
sudo yum install rubygem-heroku
```

If you are using RVM, do this

```
rvm use system
```

use heroku client.

Had a hard time making heroku command work with rvm+jruby

Answer (score 1):

You should totality go for the standalone option which is way more stable.
I had the gem installed as well and I got into a lot type of errors (ssl, cert, yours...)

You can go to:

> https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone

and install it depending on your OS.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you install the rubygem_heroku package, it likely installs the gem in the system ruby.

Based on your examples, you're using RVM.

You should install the heroku gem directly into the RVM environment and gemset you want to use it in:

```
gem install heroku
```

Comment: I end up getting the same error message when I do it directly as "rvmsudo gem install heroku"